# Modify Eclipse RCP startup args in protected directory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am enabling internationalization for my RCP application.  The preferences tab allows the user to select between languages.  I understand that Eclipse (3.7) has to load the language at start-up and can not dynamically change languages.

I know of three approaches to accomplish this:
1) Modify the OS level shortcut to pass in -nl XX
2) Change the app.ini file to have -nl XX (on separate lines)
3) Change the config.ini to have osgi.nl = XX

The issue with these approaches is that they all require write permission to the application directory.  When running under Vista / Windows 7 and Linux implementations that do not provide write access to programs, a normal user does not have permissions to modify these files.

Is there another approach to pass in arguments that change the VM language?  Is there a workaround for the file protection provided by the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows the application directory is write-protected for a good reason. Fortunately one can set **Eclipse Runtime Options** to configure where the RCP application should store

- **configuration data**
- **workspace data**

This can be accomplished in two ways:

- **setting command line arguments** (-configuration , -data)
- **defining system properties** (osgi.configuration.area to , osgi.instance.area to ) for example in *config.ini*

For further information see [Runtime Options in official Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html).

In Windows such data should be stored in the user directory. 
By the way you should be able to locate these settings in the **Installation Details** pane of the **standard About dialog**.

However setting these properties is a bit tricky. In my case the **application installer** evaluates the location of the **user directory** at installation time and modifies the *config.ini* file accordingly.